# Scheme of dual numbers over a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $D:=\operatorname{Spec}(k[t]/(t^2)$ the scheme of dual numbers over $k$.

Then what is the fibre product $D \times_k D$ with itself over $k$?
In other words, what is $\operatorname{Spec}(k[t]/(t^2) \otimes_k k[t]/(t^2)$
And how do line bundles over this scheme look like?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tensor product  $k[t]/(t^2)\otimes k[t]/(t^2)$ is equal to $k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$, where $k[x,y]$ is the polynomial ring in the two variables $x,y$ over $k$, together with the natural maps $f,g: k[t]/(t^2)\rightarrow k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$, $f(t+(t^2))=x+(x^2)$, $g(t+(t^2))=y+(y^2)$.

Proving the universal property is a bit lengthy but straightforward as far as I see.

Comment: It is not lengthy, $R[x]/(p) \otimes_R R[y]/(q) = R[x,y]/(p,q)$ is just abstract nonsense (compare hom-functors and use universal properties).

Answer (score 5):

As Hagen explained, the scheme $X=D\times_{k} D$ is the affine scheme associated to the ring  $R=k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2)$.
Since that ring is local, $all$ vector bundles of any rank on $X$ are trivial, not only line bundles .
Indeed vector bundles (or equivalently locally free sheaves $\mathcal F$) on $X$ correspond to finitely generated projective $R$-modules $P$ ( $\mathcal F \leftrightarrow \tilde P$ ) and all projective modules on a local ring  are trivial.